# Data loading on Ruby on Rails stops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Ruby on Rails 5 as a backend and Angular 5 as a frontend. I run the application on localhost for testing. And the problem is that the rails from time to time hang. And because of this, the Angular cease to display information.And the Ruby on Rails process needs to be restarted for the information to start displaying again. But to restart you have to first kill the process and then run again. Nothing serious is not loaded so that the application freezes.

Because of this, there is such an error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/users 504 (Gateway Time-out)
>   Failed to load http://localhost:3000/users: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 504.

How to fix it?

cors.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '127.0.0.1:4200', 'localhost:4200'
    resource '*',
             :headers => :any,
             :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
             :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
  end
end
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: ********************************************
  username: **********
  password: **********

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ********************************************
  username: **********
  password: **********


test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'logs'
gem 'logstasher'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', require: false
end
```

If you need to show something else write

Comment: You mean your rails server hangs up in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

you need to analyze your request

specifically check the request origin header value and the response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

if those 2 values differ, your request will be blocked

[image: request]

[image: response]

instructions at

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors